# retrofit2.HttpException при переходе с Rx на корутины

Tags: android, http, retrofit, coroutine

Перевожу проект с RxJava на корутины и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Когда отсутствует интернет при попытке запроса на сервер приложение падает с ошибкой:

> retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)
>           at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory$BodyCallAdapter$adapt$2.onResponse(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt:104)

Использую интерцептор для кеширования.

```
  val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(ResponseCacheInterceptor())
        .addInterceptor(OfflineResponseCacheInterceptor(context))
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .cache(Cache(File(context.cacheDir, "ResponsesCache"), (10 * 1024 * 1024).toLong()))
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
```

С RxJavaCallAdapterFactory все работало нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вы используете адаптер `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory` (судя по логам в нём и происходит ошибка) который уже не нужен, т.к. c retrofit 2.6.0 можно использовать suspend методы (на github странице адаптера "This library is deprecated. Please migrate to Retrofit 2.6.0 or newer and its built-in suspend support"). Попробуйте от него избавиться. Т.е. все ваши методы в интерфейсе сделать suspend, и возвращать не Deferred<MyData>, а просто MyData.

Comment: убрал CoroutineCallAdapterFactory, убрал Deferred. Все равно падает если нет интернета с этой же ошибкой

Comment: Надо запускать корутину в SuperviserJob + IO + CoroutineExceptionHandler. Тогда эксепшн вылетит именно в exceptionHandler.